# Why is floor(5 - 2*eps) < 5 false?

Tags: matlab, floating-accuracy, floor

It seems absurd to me that Matlab would evaluate `floor(5-eps) < 5` as false.
In fact, even `floor(5-2*eps) < 5` is false.

This is what I would consider a bug, as `eps` is only about `1e-16` -- far from the minimum double value. Is there a specific reason why Matlab returns false? What's the idea there?

Comment: Try replacing `eps` with `eps(5)` and see what happens.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: +1 just saw your comment, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just saw your comments, I didn't know eps took an argument! I'll mark the answer below when SO lets me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `eps(x)`, not just `eps`

> eps(X) is the positive distance from abs(X) to the next larger in magnitude floating point number of the same precision as X.

In fact, if you compare the HEX representation of `x` and `x+eps(x)`, normally they should differ by one bit in the mantissa:

```
>> format hex
>> x = 5
x =
   4014000000000000
>> x + eps(x)
ans =
   4014000000000001
```

Comment: an over-simplification of `x+eps(x)` would be: `typecast(typecast(x,'uint64')+1, 'double')` (obviously that won't always work)